# Drag & drop files into drupal site?

Tags: 7, files, media

Does anyone know of a module that allows to drag files from users computer into a target area in site (like in gmail or wordpress)?
ideally this would work with Image and other modules to insert the file "correctly" into drupal, save uploader info and allow adding meta data for file (like in the wordpress media area).

Comment: Is there anything that works for forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to give the [Plup Module](http://drupal.org/project/plup) a try. It allows you to modify your content types with a plup field for drag and drop uploads.

Comment: PlUpload is apparently the library used by WordPress for the same task (although it seems the implementation is a bit more complicated using several other libraries for browsers that aren't supported by it).
This is the sort of direction I was looking for, Thank you!
I'll give a try, and if it works as advertised I'll mark your solution as the answer.

Comment: Well, tested... not as nice as the WP implementation, but seems to be quite as capable... only need to apply it as a File PLUPL Widget in addition to the image widget, but that is peanuts... I'm sure future module version will allow more customization and options....

Answer (score 3):

I've tried several solutions using the [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module with [Plupload](http://drupal.org/project/plupload) with drag and drop capability, but I have never gotten them to work the way I want. I don't like the way Media handles files and even though I can bulk upload them into the Media area, when I want to connect them to an individual node, I still have to select them individually with an awkward media browser. Not a fan.

However, I have been VERY pleased with [Multiupload Imagefield Widget](http://drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget) (requires: [Multiupload Filefield Widget](http://drupal.org/project/multiupload_filefield_widget)). It works with a standard Image field, no need to change your content structure or do anything weird. All you need to do is edit the Widget Type on your Image field and change it from Image to Multiupload.

It will let you use the standard Image field upload, but you'll be able to select multiple images at once and upload them all with one click.

Answer (score 2):

Since October 2013, the [dragndrop_upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/dragndrop_upload) module has become available. (*Completely different* from dragndrop_uploads recommended already.) At the current time, it seems to be the most sophisticated solution to me. Worked flawlessly for me, and can be styled very nicely.

Another alternative is [dragdropfile](https://www.drupal.org/project/dragdropfile). Did not test it though.

Answer (score 1):

Questions a little old now but ..

http://drupal.org/project/dragndrop_uploads gives you the ability to drop onto a node body textarea. I've not used it so dont know how well it works. Weather it provides all the functionality your after I dont know, but it seems to be the best option out there

Another thing - while no way near as 'snazzy' and not really what you after, just thought I'd mention you can also drag files onto the 'choose file' button. I am pretty sure this works on all sites providing you have a decent browser, and that is not just a Drupal thing.

Comment: I checked this module, it hasn't been updated in a very long time. and did not work for me when I installed it on a V7 installation I have. I'm not sure what is wrong, but no combination I tried worked.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8, there's an initiative to get this functionality into core.  See [File Field design update](https://www.drupal.org/node/2113931) for details.  Let's combine all of our efforts over there.