# File upload drag and drop

Tags: 7, files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drag & drop files into drupal site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30436/drag-drop-files-into-drupal-site)

I need to implement drag and drop file upload functionality.  Does Drupal make this easy somehow?  Should I use a JS toolkit, like Dojo or Mootools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although -dev for D7, You could try http://drupal.org/project/dragndrop_uploads

> The Drag'n'Drop Uploads module adds the ability to drag an image from
>   your local filesystem, drop it onto a node body textarea and have the
>   file automatically uploaded and referenced in your node.